# forge.topbar Text Color

Tags: trigger.io

How do you set the text color of a forge.topbar native top bar in Trigger.io?

I see `setTint` which changes the background but nothing to change the color of the text in the title and buttons.

We're wanting the background color to be light and the text dark.. but as far as I can tell the text can only be white unless you use an icon instead of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not currently supported, as of v1.4.31 - you could use a title image instead if you want (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/topbar.html#settitleimage)?